# Generating a 3D figure in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, isosurface

I want to generate a figure from a 3D dataset which has values in the range [-1,1]. I want all the positive values to be in one color and the negative values to be in blank space.

I could generate this:
[image: this]

using `isosurface` and `patch` with:

```
figure(1); clf;
p1=patch(isosurface(xx,yy,zz,real(u),0.));
set(p1,'FaceColor','r','EdgeColor','none'); daspect([1 1 1])
camlight;lighting phong; box on; axis image;
view(45,45);
```

I want to generate a figure similar to this:
[image: this]

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16XUJHeAp-0mE013Rv5eeJMItenMllX15/view?usp=sharing) is the drive link for `u.mat` used in my code.

Comment: So what’s wrong with your result then? The figure you want to emulate represents different data, it likely plotted it in the same way?

Comment: You can add the surfaces where the cube cuts the data by creating separate patches for those planes.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, the dataset is different. In my figure, only the 0 surface is plotted, not all the positive regions.
What do you mean by adding surfaces? Will it look "solid" like in the reference figure?

Comment: Yeah. You have surfaces between positive and negative regions. If you add surfaces between positive regions and the outside of the data cube, then the surfaces will completely cover the positive regions, making them look solid.

Comment: @CrisLuengo How do I do it? Create new patches at different intervals say 0.1, 0.2, ... 1.0, and plot them in red?